Python numexpr: Evaluating complex numbers in scientific notation yields 'ValueError'
I am using the Python numexpr module to evaluate user inputs (numeric or formula). Numbers can be complex, and this works as long as I'm avoiding scientific notation:
>>> import numexpr as ne
>>> ne.evaluate("1000000000000j")
array(0.+1.e+12j)
>>> ne.evaluate("0.+1.e+12j")
ValueError: Expression 0.+1.e+12j has forbidden control characters.

I tried to evaluate complex numbers in scientific notation with some variations and was expecting numexpr to process these numbers. However, I always ended up with the ValueError described above.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

This is a bug in numexpr - ne.evaluate("0.+1.e+12j", sanitize=False) would fix it, but is somewhat unsafe since the raw user input gets passed to eval().  But it doesn't look like you actually need numexpr here - the built-in ast.literal_eval() safely handles expressions like this without problem, numexpr only gives a benefit when dealing with large Numpy arrays.

ast.literal_eval() is a good idea for simple user input evaluation (and I might use for that) but I also evaluate expressions like A1 * abs(sin(2 * pi * f1 * n)) where n is an array.

The errors you see with numexpr when trying to evaluate the expression "0.+1.e+12j" are due to the fact that numexpr parses complex numbers differently than standard Python. It does not accept "0.+1.e+12j" as valid because it prefers expressions where operations between numerical and logical units are explicitly defined.
However, if you reformify the expression to "1.e+12 * 1j", numexpr handles it correctly because this option explicitly separates the scalar and imaginary units by the multiplication operation, which numexpr can be handled effectively:
>>> ne.evaluate("1.e+12 * 1j")
array(0.+1.e+12j)


That's a good idea, I'll try that.

It is a bug as @jason commented:
https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/442#issuecomment-1754515334
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54449
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54542

use ast instead
import ast
ast.literal_eval("0.+1.e+12j")

numexpr uses eval() which is a big security concern.

I got bitten by this bug as well and reported it but in recent numexpr versions simple complex numbers are evaluated correctly. I'll probably try ast.literal_eval() for simple user input evaluation (see my comment above).

Yup... good luck.
